# Issue installing and referencing CPAN module in Strawberry Perl on Windows 7

Tags: perl-module

I have downloaded a perl module cfrom CPAN using Strawberry Perl's CPAN client tool. It got successfully installed. I wrote a small perl script to use the module. But I am getting the following error:

Undefined subroutine &main::chisquare called at C:\MyPadreFiles\UseChiSquare.pl
line 9.
Press any key to continue . . .

My perl code is given below:

use strict;
use warnings;

use Statistics::Chisquare;

my(@subwaystops) = (14,18,23,28,34,42,50,59,66,72,79,86,96,103);

print chisquare(@subwaystops);

I even tried Statistics::Chisquare::chisquare(@subwaystops);

But still the same undefined subroutine error. Please let me know how to resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in my code. The corrected one is given below:

use Statistics::Chisquare; wrong one

use Statistics::ChiSquare; correct one

Thanks